# Use setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) vs save() restore()

Tags: animation, canvas, transform

I've got this code working to rotate / move two boxes independently, while keeping a third stationary to confirm static base transform.   I was finally able to get it working by using setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) after unsuccessfully applying save() restore() after each transform sequence.   Although its now working I'm still wondering if there is a correct sequence of save/restore that solved the problem instead of resetting the transform.

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"> 
</canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
canvasWidth=500;
canvasHeight=500;

// box 1
var x=250;
var y=250;
var box = 50;
var angle1 = 90;

//box 2
var x2=200;
var y2=200;
var box = 50;
var angle2 = 90;

function rotate() {
angle1-=1;
angle2+=1;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
ctx.save();

//box 1
x=x-2;
y=y+2;
var ctrX = x+box/2;
var ctrY = y+box/2;

//box 2
x2=x2+.5;
y2=y2+.5;
var ctrX2 = x2+box/2;
var ctrY2 = y2+box/2;

// box 1
ctx.translate(ctrX, ctrY);//-------------------------------- move reg to center 
box
ctx.rotate(angle1 / 60);//----------------------------------rotate
ctx.translate(-ctrX, -ctrY);//-------------------------------- move reg back same 
amt

//------------------------------------------------------- draw
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, box, box);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(ctrX-5, ctrY-5, 10, 10);

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------- second box
ctx.translate(ctrX2, ctrY2);//-------------------------------- move reg to center 
box
ctx.rotate(angle2 / 60);//----------------------------------rotate
ctx.translate(-ctrX2, -ctrY2);//-------------------------------- move reg back 
same amt

//------------------------------------------------------- draw
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(x2, y2, box, box);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x2, y2, 10, 10);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(ctrX2-5, ctrY2-5, 10, 10);

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

ctx.fillStyle = "black";//............................. draw control point
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 10, 10);
ctx.restore();
}

setInterval(rotate, 100);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Resetting the transform matrix is the way to go.

`save()` / `restore()` saves and restores **all** your settable context's properties; for the memory, this has a cost, and ultimately for perfs too, while resetting the matrix sets a single property of the context and implies no memory use.
Only `clip()` requires it, but `clip()` itself should be avoided by the use of compositing.

Added to that that, this methods implies a `goto()` logic in your code and makes it harder to read, with no clear statements of what is the current state, and it also makes it easy to miss one `restore()` and let your code create a memory leak.

To answer your question, you have to understand how this operation works.

As I already said `save()` saves all the settable properties of your context, it will store it in a stack, where `restore()` will then
pop the last one to be restored.

This means that to be able to restore to a previous state, you'd need to save at least as many times as you'll need to restore.

So you could either replace all your `setTransform` lines with

```
ctx.restore(); // apply popped state
ctx.save(); // push current (restored) state
```

or you could call directly as many times `save()` as you'll need it in tour function (here 3).

But anyway, just go the `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` way.